# Cannot deploy smart contract with Eris / Monax

Tags: smartcontracts, eris-blockchain

I'm following the [Getting Started Tutorial](https://monax.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/), using eris version 0.12.0

I stuck at the point where to deploy the smart contract ~/.eris/apps/idi/idi.sol

```
eris pkgs do --chain simplechain --address $addr
```

By random I get either of following two errors:

```
Performing action. This can sometimes take a wee while
Could not perform pkg action service: Could not perform pkg action: Docker: {"m
ssage":"Cannot link to a non running container: /simplechain-a49e7fc2-45d4-44df
83bf-1dfab6246c13 AS /interactive-67fff395-600b-4161-912b-df11dc6b2807/chain"}
```

or:

```
Performing action. This can sometimes take a wee while
Could not perform pkg action service: Docker: {"message":"Invalid container name
(.eris_tmp_-798bc8a1-70bb-45fd-ac23-8468503cdbad), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.
-] are allowed"}
```

When I install eris version 0.11.4 the error looks like this:

```
Performing action. This can sometimes take a wee while
Sorry, the marmots were unable to load the eris-pm jobs file. Please check your
path.
ERROR =>                        Unsupported Config Type ""

Container interactive-39ac3a49-52fa-4f1d-953e-1662b1af7f21 exited with status 1
```

I restarted Docker Quickstart Terminal several times and also deleted the default VM in VirtualBox.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: I encountered exact same problem. (invalid container name error and couldn't not perform pkg action). Have you solved this problem? I ensured that there's not space in package.json file, and iris is running on docker-machine perfectly well).

Comment: I got the invalid container name error if I run on the .eris folder, and i got the "Post https://compilers.monax.io:10120: dial tcp: lookup compilers.monax.io on 10.0.2.3:53: no such host" when i run it in the idi folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to David's answer, you also should run
`eval $(docker-machine env eris)` to activate the docker-image.

Answer (score 0):

I had been missing the eris docker-machine running. You can check this with

```
docker-machine ls
```

And you can recreate it with:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox eris
```

Thanks to quick help from Monax / Eris team.